# XmlRootElement annotation at abstract class - possible?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class Bar {
}

public final class Foo extends Bar {
    @XmlElement
    public String getMsg() {
        return "hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to marshall an instance of class `Foo`:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "Foo" as 
an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

What is a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you get away without the @XmlRootElement annotation on the superclass.  Instead you should put it on each of your subclasses.  JAX-B will still know about the superclass fields.